# Какой паттерн проектирования используется для работы с внешними данными?

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Имеется стороннее api для получения данных(только чтение). Поскольку данные приходят в виде json/xml, то хотелось бы их как-то преобразовать в объект для удобной работы.

Какой паттерн проектирования, используется для подобных целей?

Comment: Не знаю паттерн это или кто. Сериализация/десериализация, маршалинг/унмаршалинг. Просто экспорт/импорт без затей:)

Comment: Вы ради 1-2 строчек кода собрались что-то там проектировать? Народ совсем с ума сошел с этим ООП

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [абстрактную фабрику](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Creational/AbstractFactory/README.html)

Код получения - у Вас всегда будет одинаков, но если данные изменят формат, либо Вы захотите получить дополнительные данные из других источников, которые могут иметь другой формат - то обновить скрипт не составит труда добавив 2 класса нового формата к этому шаблону.

ПыСы, в комментарии написали про 1-2 строчек кода, тем более когда шаблоны можно точно так же скопировать-вставить и времени на их реализацию уйдет не так много, если понимать о чем идет речь, это может быть полезно.

Например, я буквально на прошлой неделе решил делать импорт из 1с через абстрактную фабрику - данные приходили в CSV, соответственно у меня просто были CSVReader и CSVItem в этом шаблоне, потом клиент попросил полностью скопировать базу товаров с боевого сайта, с одной стороны я мог бы сделать экспорт с боевого в CSV и так же принимать данные, как из 1с, но я не хотел каждый раз копировать файлы, поэтому просто написал простенький Rest API который выводит данные в JSON формате, в итоге выбор изначального шаблона мне помог, так как я использовал тот же самый скрипт, просто добавил 2 новых класса JSONReader и JSONItem